# Ember.js embedded in Rails doesn't load (any) view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I am trying to embed an Ember app in my Rails view, but I can't get a simple view to load.

Relevant part of gemfile:

```
gem "ember-rails"
gem 'ember-source'
gem 'emblem-rails'
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require underscore
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/paper.js/dist/paper-full.min.js
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
... some more
//= require_tree .

window.Tabbasco2 = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember',
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_BINDINGS: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
    LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION: true,
    LOG_VERSION: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
    LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
    debugMode: true,
});

Tabbasco2.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  //templateName: 'nav'
})

Tabbasco2.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    // Do stuff
  }
})
```

And here is the HAML for the Rails view that is loading:

```
... other html

#ember

    -# http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html5_custom_data_attributes
    %script#application{ :type => 'text/x-handlebars', :data => {:template_name => 'application' }}
      {{outlet}}

    %script{ :type => 'text/x-handlebars', :data => {:template_name => 'index' }}
      test

... other html
```

The ember folders controllers, helpers, models etc are listed directly under /app/assets/javascripts

The strange thing about this is that no matter what I seem to try, Ember never logs anything more than the bootstrapping info from ember itself. The application just doesn't seem to load even though I can see in the network inspector that all the javascript is being loaded. In the chrome console:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.js:3522DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0
ember.js:3522DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
ember.js:3522DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
ember.js:3522DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.js:3522DEBUG: For more advanced debugging, install the Ember Inspector from     https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi
```

Ember does find the templates, as can be seen in the Ember object:

```
> Ember.TEMPLATES
Object
    -> application: function (context, options) {
    -> index: function (context, options) {
    -> __proto__: Object
```

However, it doesn't seem to even try loading anything. Should I setup routing differently? Reorder the Controller or View? My page is loading under the following Rails route:

`get '/partiture/show/:hash/', to: 'partitures#show'`

I must be overlooking something very simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, after giving up, an error appeared in the console saying that Ember-Data was being loaded but that no `Tabbasco2.Store` had been defined. After defining it it worked. Which is strange as I had defined it before.

So, I don't know why it suddenly works, but it works.